# How to copy paste cells into respective columns in Excel vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel 2007 sheet where column names with data are all placed in one single column and I need to shift one column name to the left or right with data so that I can have separate columns. Can you create a VBA function where it reads all rows of the column and shift those columns with certain keywords. Such as:

```
A1   B1
1     **Category1**
      Cat1 info here
      **cf**
      45
      34
      34
      Sf
      542
      234
      234
2     **Category2**
      Cat2 info here
      **cf**
      76
      23
      67
      **Sf**
      678
      987
      3476
```

I Need to move "**cf**" column + data to a different column and paste it to its relevant category. So "cf" would shift right with data and move up along with its category. I would then delete the empty rows of B Column.

Comment: Do you need to do this quite often or in a sheet with thousands of rows? If not, simply select the range of cells you want to shift and DRAG then right and up.

Comment: @HWQ what have you tried so far ? show us your code attempt.

Comment: @FDavidov Yes, its Thousands of rows, otherwise I would have found a way.

Comment: @ShaiRado I havent really tried anything as of yet since I couldnt figure it out.

Comment: OK. If the file is large BUT this needs to be done only once, the best way in my opinion is to RECORD a macro and then execute it. There are plenty of examples in the internet on how to do that (here is one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nvWpFdo7EO0). You can ask Excel to execute the macro once or many times. Should not be much of an issue at all.

Comment: @ShaiRado  This is what I got .. works

Answer (score 0):

Finally had it figured out, Bad coding maybe but it works.. :)

Thanks All for your Help .

```js
Sub test()
Dim i As Long
Dim toprow As Long
Dim z As Long
Dim count As Long
Dim b As Long

toprow = 3
b = toprow
For i = toprow To Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
If Not Cells(i, 1) = "" And Not Cells(i, 2) = "" Then
     b = i
     count = 0
     z = i
End If
 If Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
   If Cells(i + 1, 1) = "" Then
    z = i
    If Not Cells(z + 1, 2) = "" Then
       Cells(z + 1, 2).Cut Cells(b, 2)
       i = b
       b = z + 1
       count = 0
    ElseIf count = 0 Then
       count = z
       b = count
   End If
   
End If
End If
Next i
End Sub
```